# Leaflet translate coordinates into street addresses

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, leaflet, maps

I am creating an app where I use a leaflet map. I was wondering if there is any extern library that I can use to translate coordinates into street addresses? Im using Angular 6.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here is a really simple possibility by using **Nominatim**. It's a tool used by OpenStreetmap. Here is a link for all the details:
https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Nominatim

And here is an example on how you could use it:

```
$.get('https://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=jsonv2&lat=47.217954&lon=-1.552918', function(data){
    console.log(data.address.road);
});
```

You will only need to replace coordinates with variable like this:

```
lat='+ latitude +'
```

And if you want a plugin: https://esri.github.io/esri-leaflet/examples/reverse-geocoding.html

Answer (score 3):

What you are asking for is called [Geocoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geocoding). For Leaflet there is a plethora of plugins to accomplish this, all of them listed at https://leafletjs.com/plugins#geocoding. Note that some plugins, such as https://github.com/perliedman/leaflet-control-geocoder, are not limited to one geocoding provider.